# How to set colspan dynamically using jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, html-table

Hi i am displaying time tables. I want to add colspan dynamically to an element which contains string Lab. The table stored in database as follow:-

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    Day  | 9-10       | 10-11 | 11-12 | 12- 1| 1-2 |  2-3                |  3-4 |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Monday  | DA601     | DA602 | DA603 |      |     | DA602 Lab/DA603 Lab  |      |
| Tuesday | DA601 Lab |       |       |      |     | DA602 Lab/DA603 Lab  |      |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So when the table is displayed in the application i want to colspan the lab entry so that it display in 2-3 and 3-4. I am unable to think of a way to do it. Kindly please provide a way to do it with javascript/jquery or any other technique.

Table Display Code:-

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-xxs">
    <thead>
        <tr class="bg-info-600">
             <th>Day</th>
             <th>9-10</th>
             <th>10-11</th>
             <th>11-12</th>
             <th>12-1</th>
             <th>1-2</th>
             <th>2-3</th>
             <th>3-4</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
       <?php 
            $sql="SELECT * FROM tt" ; 
            $results = $timetable->query($sql);
            while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) 
            {
                echo '<tr>'; 
                echo "<td>{$row['day']}</td>"; 
                echo "<td>{$row['9-10']}</td>"; 
                echo "<td>{$row['10-11']}</td>"; 
                echo "<td>{$row['11-12']}</td>"; 
                echo "<td>{$row['12-1']}</td>"; 
                echo "<td>{$row['1-2']}</td>"; 
                echo "<td>{$row['2-3']}</td>"; 
                echo "<td>{$row['3-4']}</td>"; 
                echo '</tr>';                       
            }
        ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
$('table tbody tr td').each(function(){
    var value = $(this).html();
    if(value.indexOf("LAB") !== -1){ //true
        $(this).attr("colspan", 2);
        $(this).next("td").remove(); // removes extra td 
    }
});
```

This iterates through each `<td>`. If `LAB` is found in the HTML contents of this cell apply the attribute `colspan`. and delete the next cell which **should** be blank. This is done because we are simply expanding the current cell across 2 columns, not overriding the next cells data, which creates an "extra" `td` cell.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/imclarky/z6yc83e6/2/)

**Note:** This assumes the length of a Lab session is fixed at 2 hours long.

Comment: @KartikeyVishwakarma I still didn't understand what you actually wanted? `:O`

Comment: @PraveenKumar - basically, if a table cell has `Lab` in it, make it span 2 `<td>`s as "Lab" sessions last 2 hours. Look at the fiddle... it gives a representation of before and after.

Comment: @ImClarky Thanks for the clarification. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

you can use `.attr()` to set `colspan` dynamically

The `:nth-child(n)` selector selects all elements that are the nth child, regardless of type, of their parent.

```
$("table tr:nth-child(7)").attr('colspan',2);
```

Comment: Won't that make every element appearing there to colspan. What if there is no lab entry there but is some place else.